# Send Multiple Object through TCP without Closing or Disposing Stream

Tags: c#, tcp

I had using the BinaryFormatter to Serialize an object through NetworkStream
The code like this

```
//OpenConnection ...
TCPClient client = server.AcceptTCPConnection();
Message message = new Message("bla bla"); // This is the serializable class
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream(); // Get Stream
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(stream, message);
stream.Flush();
stream.Close(); //Close Connection
```

And in client Code, we just need to Read from stream
`bf.Deserialize(stream) as Message`
to get the object we just sent from Server.

But there is a problem here, if I delete the line `stream.Close();` the client cannot read this Object. Or I can change to `stream.Dispose();`

However, I want to use this stream again to send another `Message`, how I can do? Please help, it make me feel so headache @@

**UPDATE:**
I found the reason of this issue. Because I used one machine to run both client and server. It definitely worked well in two different machines. Someone can tell me why? Get big problem with this for a couple day ago.

Comment: "the client cannot read this Object" Why?

Comment: @usr *usually* this is the issue of looking for the end of an open network socket (i.e. where there is no framing)

Comment: I recognize that pattern, but I assumed that BinaryFormatter can detect the end of its message precisely. Probably a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Sending multiple separate messages involves "framing" - splitting the single channel into separate chunks that don't ever require the client to "read to end". Oddly, though, I was under the impression that `BinaryFormatter` *already implemented* basic framing - but: I could be wrong. In the general case, when working with a binary protocol, the most common approach is to prefix each message with the length of the payload, i.e.

```
using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    while(...)
    {
        // not shown: serialize to ms

        var len BitConverter.GetBytes((int)ms.Length);
        output.Write(len, 0, 4);
        output.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int) ms.Length);
        ms.SetLength(0); // ready for next cycle
    }
}
```

the caller has to:

- read exactly 4 bytes (at least, for the above), or detect EOF
- determine the length
- read exactly *that* many bytes
- deserialize
- repeat

If that sounds like a lot of work, maybe just use a serializer that does all this for you; for example, with protobuf-net, this would be:

```
while(...) { // each item
    Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(output, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
}
```

and the reader would be:

```
foreach(var msg in Serializer.DeserializeItems<Message>(
       input, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1))
{
   // ...
}
```

(note: this does not use the same format / rules as `BinaryFormatter`)

Comment: Do you have the same problem with me when run both server and client in one machine? My code worked well in 2 different machines, I don't know why

Comment: @duykhoa probably different buffering etc, since talking to 127.0.0.1 usually uses the loopback interface to skip the NIC

Comment: 90% it's true. So, there aren't any alternative solution for this problem?

Comment: @duykhoa what problem? if you use TCP correctly, *there is no problem here*. See also: http://tiny.cc/io

Comment: The problem is: I want to test on my computer, only one :)